# A question regarding information

Tags: general-relativity, experimental-physics, faster-than-light

Consider a continuous system of cogs which extend from the sun to the earth. Light takes eight minutes to reach the earth. However, if one was to rotate the initial cog(near the sun) then the all the cogs would rotate simultaneously(I don't know is this will actually happen!) there by working as a signalling mechanism which can be used to transmit information from the sun to earth(or the other way) instantaneously. Therefore information(I don't know what information exactly means.) could be transmitted faster than the speed of light. Isn't this counter intuitive? If not where am I making a mistake? I request anyone to shed some light on this matter.

Answer (score 2):

This question has been posed in various forms on this platform, and answered.

Any information could not travel faster than the speed of sound in one cog. There will also be time delay between cogs due to clearance.

Answer (score 1):

The cogs do not all rotate simultaineously. They are made of matter, and matter interacts via the fundamental forces of nature, principally in this case electromagnetism. That means photon exchange. As the route around the cogs is somewhat longer than a straight line the information will take significantly longer to reach the earth.